# Using Process in java

Tags: c#, java

I'm converting some c# code to java

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
// Get the output into a string
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
// Display the command output.
```

This is the code that i try to convert it to java.

I dont know how to run a command  and use process in java. I googled it and i found something like that :

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
Integer result = process.exitValue();
```

In the line

```
process.exitValue()
```

it gives me `java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: process has not exited`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `exec` you need to wait for the command to finish with `process.waitFor()`.

Answer (score 0):

`process.exitValue()` gets the number from `System.exit(number)`
The error is thrown since the process hasn't exited yet.
From the c# code it looks like you want to get the command's output, this can be done by:

```
int i=0;
String result = new String();
while((i = process.getInputStream().read()) >= 0)
    result += (char)i;
System.out.println(result);
```